# Angular components Does not show content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a web application Using Angular.
and i created navbar with routing to different components
but when i press any button in navbar
extension appears in URL but components does not show content.
looking for some help, and thank you in advance.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-main-nav></app-main-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

main-nav.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
      #drawer
      class="sidenav"
      fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">

    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home">Home</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/about">About</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/services">Services</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/blog">Blog</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <mat-toolbar color="primary">

      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <span>Markvira</span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/home">Home</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/about">About</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/services">Services</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/blog">Blog</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Have you included AppRoutingModule in your imports array of app.module.ts file?

Comment: Hello, Hatem! I tried to reproduce your particular case but in my case navigation works fine. Probably Angular hide some errors or you just forget to include AppRoutingModule.

Comment: i already imported in my app.module.ts  `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';`

Answer (score 0):

I inspected project, and found errors due to chrome extensions.
when i disabled all chrome extensions.
project go well
thank you all for your time and support